# How to prioritise one domain name over others in rDNS?

Tags: email, dns, postfix, spam-prevention, rdns

I have a single remote server and multiple domain names. This server hosts webpages under certain domain names - say domain1.com - and hosts a webpage with an associated mail server under a separate domain name - say domain2.com.

The issue I have, is the rDNS record for my servers IP returns the domain name 'domain1.com'. I want rDNS to return 'domain2.com' instead. Due to this issue, emails being sent from my mail server are being flagged as spam as the rDNS and fDNS do not match.

I was not aware I had set my IPs rDNS to 'domain1.com'. I have only edited the DNS records for both 'domain1.com' and 'domain2.com'. After researching online, I received the impression rDNS could only be set by contacting my hosting provider. As my rDNS is set to 'domain1.com', evidently this is not the case.

So, my question is, how do I go about changing my rDNS from returning 'domain1.com' to returning 'domain2.com' ?

Some background info: My OS is Linux, hosted by IONOS. I am running Postfix as my mail server. If any additional info would be helpful please ask.

Comment: The `rDNS` or `PTR`  belongs to the IP address owner. In your case, it's IONOS company. You should have a way to change the `PTR` record for your IP address in IONOS administration interface to change it. You can check this : https://www.ionos.com/help/server-cloud-infrastructure/dedicated-server-for-servers-purchased-before-102818/network/setting-reverse-mapping-for-a-dedicated-ip-address/